Responsive Positioning on Stack
Im trying to find a way to position my widgets 100% correctly on a Stack, i use Visibility Widget with a set of flags and create a button when the user wanna cancel a "Route" of a map that she/he made .
The thing is i want to position it in the top , i know that i can use Aligment widget but i dont want to put it exactly on top , i want to put it on top AND have some space from it like 100 pixels (but for all of my screens).
Here is my code :
 Visibility(
                  visible: hasRoute,
                  child: Positioned(
                    top: 100.0,
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          route.clear();
                          hasRoute = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Clear Route',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 7, 223),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

Can i make it with a simple command or do i need to test every screen for that and put more pixels on the top?
Also how i can avoid using "                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
" and center it correctly?
Thanks.

so use something like this: Align(top center) > Padding(top: 100) > ElevatedButton

Sorry for the late answer . Yiep worked my bad , i had some animations and changed the positioned last time i tried with padding ,i thought it was a bug .Now works . Fixed  Thanks .
